# How to automatically create a tag label in svn whenenver a build is pinned

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, teamcity

Is there a way to cause TeamCity to automatically create a label in subversion whenever a build is pinned?

The idea is that after a build is pinned (with a tag entry) TeamCity will take that tag entry and create an identical tag in svn.

Background: We nightly build a setup of our project. This setup then is used internally to install and test the application. About every two weeks or so we release the application to our customer so that it can be tested there as well. This release we pin in TeamCity and set the tag when pinning to the program version. We now would like to label the source with this tag as well.

I'm aware that I can manually cause labeling with "Label this build source". However, I would like to have an automated process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the only way to implement this functionality is to write a plugin for TeamCity.
  The related documentation can be found [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD9/Developing+TeamCity+Plugins).

In the plugin, you can add a listener (which extends BuildServerAdapter).
  You implement hooks buildTagsChanged or buildPinned.
  You use method VcsLabelManager#setLabel to set the label for the build.

Regards,
  KIR

Comment: @Christoph did you end up building such a plugin? I'm also interested in this functionality.

Comment: I requested this as a feature in TeamCity: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-36729

Comment: @KIR: Would you mind updating the link in your reply, as it has become out-of-date and is inaccessible...? Also, could you perhaps illustrate in a short example how this would look with the latest API (8.1.x/9.x)? Many thanks!

Comment: I've corrected the link; API hasn't changed since the post with regard to this issue.